# How to get DDMStructre by using ddmStructureKey in liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

In liferay 6.2 we can use 
DDMStructureLocalServiceUtil using ddmStructureKey  to get a DDMStructure.

In liferay 7 or DXP how to get DDM Structure using ddmStructureKey  ?

Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

Inject DDMStructureLocalServic in your components with the @Reference annotation.

```
@Reference
private DDMStructureLocalServic service;
```

To enable property annotations add this dependency to your Gradle file.

```
org.osgi:org.osgi.service.component.annotations:1.3.0
```

Comment: following error while deploying.package com.liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.model does not exist
import com.liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.model.DDMStructure; while adding following call:DDMStructure ddmStructure= structureLocalService.getStructure(groupId,classNameId, ddmStructureKey)

Comment: did you add all required dependencies? DDM was moved out of the kernel and needs to be defined as separate dependency.

Comment: I have added dependency of DDM.. how to get classNameId  DDMStructure ddmStructure= structureLocalService.getStructure(groupId,classNameId, ddmStructureKey);

Comment: classNameLocalService